# Sum of Shift Operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, self-adjoint-operators

I have the operator $T: l_2[0,\infty) \to l_2[0, \infty)$ defined by $T=S_l+S_r$. So $T(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3,...)=(x_1, x_2+x_0,x_3+x_1,x_4+x_2,...)$.

I've shown that it's spectrum is a subset of $[-2,2]$.

What's left is to show is that $\left\lVert T \right\rVert =2$. It was easy to show that $\left\lVert T \right\rVert \leq 2$, but getting it equal to $2$ is tripping me up. Any help is appreciated.

Also, what is the best way to show the spectrum of T is indeed $[-2,2]$. I don't have much practice finding the continuous spectrum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only want to see that the norm is $2$, consider
$$
x=(\overbrace{1,\ldots,1}^{n},0,\ldots).
$$
Then
$$
Tx=(1,\overbrace{2,\ldots,2}^{n-1},1,0,\ldots).
$$
So
$$
\frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|}=\frac{\sqrt{4n-2}}{\sqrt{n}}=2\,\sqrt{1-\frac2n}.
$$
As this can be done for any $n$, you get $\|T\|\geq2$.

Now, if you want to get the whole spectrum:  fix $h,r\in\mathbb N$, and let $\lambda=2\cos\frac{h\pi}{r}$. For each $m\in\mathbb N$ let $$n=mr-1, \ \ s=mh=\frac{(n+1)h}r.$$ Consider $x^{(m)}\in \ell^2$ given by
$$
x_k^{(m)}=\begin{cases} \sin\frac{ks\pi}{n+1},&\ 1\leq k\leq n\\ \ \\ 0,&\ k>n\end{cases}
$$
Then (some trigonometry involved)
$$
(Tx^{(m)})_k=\begin{cases}
2\cos\frac{s\pi}{n+1}\,\sin\frac{ks\pi}{n+1},&\ 1\leq k\leq n\\ \ \\
\sin\frac{ns\pi}{n+1},&\ k=n+1\\ \ \\ 
0,&\ k>n+1
\end{cases}
$$
As long as $h/r$ is not an integer, we have that $\|x^{(m)}\|\sim \sqrt {mr}$. Let $z^{(m)}=\frac{x^{(m)}}{\|x^{(m)}\|}$.

Since $2\cos\frac{s\pi}{n+1}=\lambda$,
$$
\|Tz^{(m)}-\lambda z^{(m)}\|=\frac1{\|x^{(m)}\|}\,\left|\sin\frac{ns\pi}{n+1}\right|\leq\frac1{\|x^{(m)}\|}\,\xrightarrow[m\to\infty]{}0.
$$
Thus $\lambda$ is an approximate eigenvalue for $T$. In other words,
$$
\left\{2\cos q\pi:\ q\in\mathbb Q\right\}\subset\sigma(T).
$$
As the spectrum is closed and the cosine continuous,
$$
[-2,2]=\{2\cos t\pi:\ t\in\mathbb R\}\subset\sigma(T). 
$$

Comment: I think there's something wrong with your sequence $x^{(m)}$, because it doesn't really depend on m, if we write $s$ as $\frac{(n+1)h}{r}$, then the sequence will be just $\sin \frac{kh}{r}$, and $||Tx-x||$ doesn't go to zero, because $s$ depends on $m$.

Comment: $n$ also depends on $m$.

Comment: Yes, but $s$ also depends on m, and  $|\sin (\frac{ns \pi} {n+1})| = |\sin (\frac{nh\pi}{r})| = |\sin(mh \pi - \frac{h \pi}{r})| =|\sin (\frac{h \pi}{r})|$, it doesn't depend on $m$, so limit will not be zero.

Comment: I think, that we can correct the sequence a little. If we take the new sequence to be $y^{(m)} = \frac{1}{||x^{(m)}||} x^{(m)}$, then $||Ty^{(m)} - \lambda y^{(m)}|| = |\frac{\sin (\frac{h\pi}{r})}{||x^{(m)}||}| \to 0$, since $||x^{(m)}|| \to \infty$ as the sequence $x^{(m)}$ becomes longer, when m increases.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, thanks for noticing!. I'll edit that in.